# Renaming files based on creation date with respect to a folder they're in

Tags: python

I have a folder that contains subfolders, and in subfolders there are files. I'd like to rename the files, numbering them from 1, ascending by date they've been created, but the part I've been struggling with, is that every subfolder should be renamed separately. So, subfolder1 would have files named 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, but subfolder2 would also have 1.txt, 2.txt etc.

What I have right now is a sorted dictionary of pairs of all files and their creation time, with no regard to a subfolder containing them, but I don't know how to proceed.

```
import os.path, time

file_path = 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test

for dirpath, folders, files in os.walk(file_path):
    files_creation_dates = {}
    for file in files:
        file_creation_date = time.ctime(os.path.getctime(f'{dirpath}\\{file}'))
        files_creation_dates[file] = file_creation_date
    sorted_files = sorted(files_creation_dates.items(), key=lambda single_file: single_file[1])
```

Comment: store the results in a dictionary whose keys are the directories:
```results = {}```
and then:
```results[dirpath] = sorted_files```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os.path, time

file_path = 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test

results = {}
for dirpath, folders, files in os.walk(file_path):
    files_creation_dates = {}
    for file in files:
        file_creation_date = time.ctime(os.path.getctime(f'{dirpath}\\{file}'))
        files_creation_dates[file] = file_creation_date
    sorted_files = sorted(files_creation_dates.items(), key=lambda single_file: single_file[1])
    results[dirpath] = sorted_files
```

Comment: Thank you, I think now I know what to do next. I'm not quite sure why in the last line we have `sorted_files` as values, would you elaborate on that?

Comment: If I understood your objective, you wanted the list of files in sorted order for each directory (or subdirectory).  The dictionary organizes your data this way; Each directory (the keys) and the list of sorted files as values.